# Unable to retrieve the value from a form with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to validate my form, but I can't seem to capture my form values! At a loss as to where to go now. I've tried a combination of jQuery and Javascript. Here's a snippet of my code.

HTML:

```
<form action="#" name="application-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <ul>
            <li class="input-row">
              <label for="app-resume">Resume</label>
              <input type="file" id="app-resume" name="resume" />
            </li>
            <li class="input-row">
              <label for="app-name">Full Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="app-name" name="fname" />
            </li>
            <li class="input-row">
              <label for="app-pnum">Phone Number</label>
              <input type="number" id="app-pnum" name="pnum" />
            </li>
            <li class="input-row">
              <label for="app-email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" id="app-email" name="email" />
            </li>
            <li class="input-row">
              <label for="app-info">Additional Information</label>
              <textarea type="text" id="app-info" name="info"></textarea>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="btn-mssg-container">
            <button type="submit" name="sbt-btn" id="sbt-btn">apply</button>
            <p id="sbt-mssg" class="hidden">Thank you for applying.</p>
          </div>
        </form>
```

JS:

```
var myForm = document.forms["application-form"];
myForm.onsubmit = processForm;
function processForm(){
  console.log(myForm.fname.value); 
}
```

I've also tried:

```
function processForm(){
  var inName = $("#app-name").val();
  console.log(inName);
}
```

I'm getting nothing! Someone please put me out of my misery.

Comment: Check console for any error. Your example using the second way works fine in codepen.

Comment: The first example seems to work fine as well. It logs what you type in the fname field.

Comment: No errors in my console - I've checked the typeof value returned and it's a string, but always empty.

Comment: I suppose that pressing "apply" triggers a page reload.

Comment: @leaf - i'm an idiot. Thank you for mentioning this. I've just been resetting my input variables to blank.

Comment: The question is, what do you want to do with the form after the button was pressed ?

Comment: @leaf I want to clear my form after hitting submit, or if they close my form (the form is wrapped in a model). Should I be reloading my form when submit is pressed?

Comment: I mean, do you want to store the data somewhere "permanently" ? This is usually what people do.

Comment: @leaf no need! I won't be collecting real information - it's just a mockup project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first attempt at getting form values is called **[HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)**

---

**1. Reference the form:**

`var FoRm = document.forms`**.FormID_or_NAME**

**OR**

`var FoRm = document.forms["`**FormID_or_NAME**`"]`

**OR**

`var FoRm = document.forms[0]`

The last one using index number zero in bracket notation will work if the target `<form>` is the first on the page or the only `<form>` on the page.

---

**2. Collect all of the form's form controls into an array-like object:**

`var formControlS = FoRm.elements`

Step 2. was the crucial step that you were missing.

---

**3. Now you can reference and get values from any form control under that specific `<form>`:**

`var foRmC = formControlS.`**FormControlID_or_NAME**`.value`

**OR**

`var foRmC = formControlS["`**FormControlID_or_NAME**`"].value`

**OR**

`var foRmC = formControlS[0].value`

---

**Details are commented in Demo**

**This localStorage feature cannot work in a Stack Snippet due to security measures. If you want to review a fully functional demo, then visit [Plunk](https://embed.plnkr.co/WyHuuUmJN3PCyNSIALon/)**

### Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #main {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
    
    iframe {
      display: inline-table;
      max-width: 40%;
      height: 100vh
    }
    
    #app0 {
      max-width: 60%;
      margin: 0 0 5px 15px;
    }
    
    label {
      display: inline-block
    }
    /* Area code - Central Office code */
    
    [type=number] {
      width: 5ch
    }
    /* The last 4 digits - Station code */
    
    label [type=number]:last-of-type {
      width: 6ch
    }
    
    [type=email] {
      width: 26ch
    }
    
    .hidden {
      opacity: 0
    }
    
    #msg {
      height: 60px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      border: 3px inset grey;
      padding: 10px;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main id='main'>
    <!-- On submit, form sends to a real test server
    || The target attribute value is the name of 
    || iframe#display. Whenver data is tested thru 
    || this server, it will send a response later. 
    -->
    <form action="https://httpbin.org/post" id="app0" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target='display'>

      <fieldset id='set0'>

        <label for="file0">Resume</label>
        <input type="file" id="file0" name="resume">
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="name0">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name0" name="name">
        <br>
        <br>

        <label>Phone Number
          <input type="number" id="area0" name="phone" min='100' max='999'>
          <input type="number" id="cent0" name="phone" min='100' max='999'>
          <input type="number" id="stat0" name="phone" min='0000' max='9999'>
        </label>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="mail0">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail0" name="mail">
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="info0">Additional Information</label>
        <br>
        <textarea id="info0" name="info" cols='28'></textarea>
        <br>

      </fieldset>

      <fieldset id="set1">
        <button id='btn' type="button" class=''>Process</button>
        <button id='sub' type='submit' class='hidden'>Transfer</button>

      </fieldset>
      <output id="msg"></output>
    </form>

    <iframe name='display' src='about:blank' width='60%'></iframe>

  </main>
  <script>
    /* The interface used to refer to form controls
        || is called HTMLFormControlsCollection
        */ // Reference the form
    var xApp = document.forms.app0;

    /*\\\\\\\\\\/IMPORTANT\//////////
    This is the part that was in error
    In order to refer to any form controls
    of the referenced form, you must
    collect them in an array-like object
    using the .elements proerty //////*/

    var xCon = xApp.elements;

    // Then from the .elements reference by id
    // A click event on a button--processForm
    // is called
    xCon.btn.onclick = processForm;

    /* This function will gather all form values
    || into an array.
    || Then it stores that array in localStorage
    || Displays the data then hides the "Process"
    || button and reveals the "Transfer" button
    */
    function processForm(e) {

      var qty = xCon.length;
      var data = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {

        var formControl = xCon[i].value;

        if (formControl !== null || formControl !== undefined || formControl !== "") {

          data.push(formControl);

        }
      }

      localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
      var stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
      appX();

      xApp.onsubmit = appX;

      function appX(e) {
        xCon.msg.value = stored;
        xCon.btn.classList.toggle('hidden');
        xCon.sub.classList.toggle('hidden');
      }
    }
    /* Once the "Transfer" button is clicked, the
    || data is sent to the test server and the
    || test server responds back. The response is 
    || captured and displayed in the iframe to the
    || right
    */
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My pleasure, happy coding